# Pulling a var out of a function

Tags: javascript, function, global, variables

Can't seem to pull a value out of a function... seems simple enough but can't get it to go. I figured it was an asyc problem but even with async:false; it still returns undefined.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var activeTab;

function toggleVisibility(selectedTab) {
//Let the navigation know what tab is selected
activeTab = selectedTab;
return activeTab;
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.write(window.activeTab);
</script>
```

And here is the call to the function

```
<a href="#" onclick="toggleVisibility('linkname');">LinkName</a>
```

Comment: the document.write is contained within an if statement like this    if (window.activeTab == "linkname"){
    document.write("<img src='images/rightnav_linkname.png' border='0'><br>");
   }... so document.write executes first no matter what?

Answer (score 2):

Your script containing document.write(window.activeTab); is running well before you click on the link, otherwise it would be overwriting your entire document, since that's what document.write does if the DOM is already loaded.

Since you're running it before you click on the link window.activeTab hasn't been assigned a value yet.

There are many solutions to this, but what solution you need depends on what you actually want to do with `activeTab`. I'm assuming you really want to use it for something, and not just `document.write` it.

**Update**

It seems you want to update an image based on the value of `window.activeTab`. Your code to update the image should also be in the onclick handler so that it executes when your link is clicked, not when your page is loading. You should also avoid `document.write` for a few reasons, but the most obvious is what I already stated: It will overwrite your entire document if the page has already loaded when you use it.

You might want to try something like:

```
<a href="#tab1" class="tabs">LinkName</a>
```

And somewhere in the page after the HTML for tabs:

```
<script>
(function(){

var tabs = document.getElementsByClassName('tabs');

// For each tab
for(var i = tabs.length; i--;){

    // Add click handler to tab
    tabs[i].onclick = switch_tab;

    // Hide tab
    a_to_tab(tabs[i]).style.display = 'none';
}

// Show first tab
a_to_tab(tabs[0]).style.display = '';



function switch_tab(){
    // Hide all tabs
    for(var j = tabs.length; j--;){
        a_to_tab(tabs[j]).style.display = 'none';
    }

    // Show this tab
    a_to_tab(this).style.display = '';

    // Cancel default onclick action
    return false;
}

// Get the tab element from the a element that refers to it by href
function a_to_tab(a){
    return document.getElementById(a.href.replace(/^[^#]*#/, ''));
}

})();
</script>
```

See this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/ZcLpa/).

You might also want to check out [jQuery UI Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/)

Comment: I see... activeTab determines what navigation graphic to display. So I am using an if statement to determine which image to display. What do you suggest?

Comment: if (window.activeTab == "linkname"){
    document.write("<img src='images/rightnav_linkname_on.png' border='0'><br>");
   }
   else {
document.write("<a href='#' onclick=\"toggleVisibility('linkname');\"><img src='images/rightnav_linkname.png' border='0'></a><br>");
   }

Comment: @user1451978 I think you're trying to make some sort of tabbed navigation, but I'm not sure. I updated my answer with some working commented code (no library). And a suggestion to check out jQuery. I hope it's helpful.

Comment: you got it... this makes sense. I'm so not used to everything executing at once on a page... I'm an old PHP guy. Thanks for your solution and being gentle with a first timer. CHEERS

Comment: @user1451978 No problem. If you feel that this answer has/will solve your problem and is the best answer posted you can accept it by hitting the check mark beside the vote count. If you want to wait and see if anyone provides an answer that is more helpful to you that is also acceptable, but at some point you should accept one answer to any question you ask on StackOverflow that you feel someone has answered fully.